# Instagram API returning 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: api, instagram

Very recently, the Instagram API has been sporadically returning 502 Bad Gateway. Anyone else seeing this? Possible to resolve?

This has been happening for a couple of weeks now, previously it was very stable.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same thing, very recently, as in, the past 3-7 days or so.
Also getting some "Oops, an error occurred" and occasionally a 504.  Each of these invalid responses are happening far more frequently than they used to

Comment: Me too. I'm getting 500s with that same "Oops, an error occurred" on unsubscribe URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, they are aware of it, have a look at their tumblr => http://developers.instagram.com/, more precisely => http://developers.instagram.com/post/82701625883/api-returning-500-errors-on-specific-ip.